# Share logged in subject with filter

Tags: java, security, single-sign-on, shiro

I'm implementing Single Sign On in a application that currently supports form authentication. I use shiro as security framework.

I have a servlet that receives saml assertions and logges in the user as following:

```java
Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
subject.login(new SAMLToken(assertions));
```

The subject is successfully authenticated, but according to the shiro specifications, only on this thread.
The problem is that I have an authentication filter that runs on a different thread and I would like that this subject to be authenticated also on that thread.

Is is possible to achieve this? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would probably create a filter [(similar to one of these)](https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#default-filters), where you convert the inbound request to your SAML token. All of the session management (and the `login()` call) would be handled for you.

For example for basic auth, a token is created from the request header:

https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/f782eb1084df73eff3e2ac0f9780cb4a4f429041/web/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/authc/BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter.java#L353-L374